# Specifying "Where" in when inserting building blocks in MS word 10 via VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I'm trying to add a custom building block at the click of a button in MS word 10. Below is the code currently attached to my activeX button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim objTemplate As Template
   Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

' Set the template to store the building block
  Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

' Access the building block through the type and category
  Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
 .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

 ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
   objBB.Insert Selection.Range
End Sub
```

My problem is, as this code is invoked at the click of a button, the button becomes the "Selection.Range" and is thus replaced. I looked all around for alternate codes that mention of different "where" specification and found nothing.

I only found two links(can't find the urls in my history rightnow, will update shortly)

1. It mentioned "Paragraphs(1)" instead of "Selection.Range", but this is an absolute location while I would need something relative (Before the button)
2. Using InsertBefore method which I suppose applies only to text (it was used to insert text in the example) as when I tried it for building blocks it didnt work

P.S I'm relatively new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to utilize `selection` at all? My word VBA might be rusty, but instead why don't you ask the user where to do it?

for excel I would -

```
sub test
dim rngslct as range
set rngslct = inputbox("Where?","Pick a range","", type := 8)
objBB.Insert rngslct
end sub
```

Now, I think [ranges work a little bit differently in word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835176.aspx), but the method is the same. Ask for input, or define the input, then alter it.

Maybe use the inputbox to return text that represents where the selection exists. Then use that input to search for the next `.paragraph` or whatever that contains that text?

[here is Word inputbox help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198340.aspx)

[word built-in dialog boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836154.aspx)

and [controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835147.aspx)

---

If you don't want to ask the user, why not look for whatever the selection should be (in relation to your button)? next `.section` or `.paragraph` or `.style` and find it that way.

---

### Here's what I came up with in word

```
Sub test()
Dim str As String
str = InputBox("what words")
Dim orng As Range
Set orng = ActiveDocument.Content
  With orng.Find
    .Text = str
  End With
    If orng.Find.Execute Then
        orng.Find.Execute
        orng.Bookmarks.Add ("bookmark1")
        Dim fnd As Range
        Set fnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bookmark1").Range
    End If
    'do stuff to fnd
End Sub
```

So now the selection you're looking for is the range `fnd`. Replace any usage of selection with that.